# How Can I Make responsive hamburger menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, navbar

How can I make this "bars" icon functional? The videos I watch on the internet confuse me. The hamburger menu I want to make is like on the following site; https://www.greenmountainenergy.com/#
I am also open to resource suggestions if you don't want to mess around because it's long. Thank you in advance for your answers.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

html{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#TopBar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1366px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.nav-menu{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1240px) {

.nav-menu-list > ul{
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-menu-list > ul > li > a{
    padding: 1.7rem 0rem;
}

.item-1:hover .dropdown{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.item-2:hover .dropdown-2{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.item-3:hover .dropdown-3{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.item-4:hover .dropdown-4{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav-menu-list > ul > li > a:hover{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-menu-list >  ul{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu-list > ul > li{
 padding-left: 2.5rem;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    left: -50px;
    width: 340px;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
    font-size: 14px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.dropdown > a > span{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
  color: #1F6099;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown > li > a{
  display: block;
  margin-top:0.6rem ;
}

.dropdown > li > a:hover{
    color: #1F6099;
}

.dropdown > .bold-text > a{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown > .space > a{
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.dropdown-2{
    left: 135px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}


.dropdown-3{
    left: 260px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.dropdown-4{
    left: 410px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.nav-menu .nav-menu-list, .nav-menu-list2{
    display: flex;
}

.nav-menu-list2 > ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-menu-list2 > ul > li{
    padding-left: 2.3rem;
}

.nav-menu-list2 .item-2{
    color: #1F6099;
}

.nav-menu-list2 i{
    padding-right: 0.7rem;
}

.icon{
  display: none;
}

.list ul{
  transition: all .8s ease;
}

}

.orange-btn{
  padding: 12px 15px;
    background-color: #F47825;
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1239px) {
  .nav-menu-list{
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-menu-list2{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='global.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" /></head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
<body>
    <nav id="TopBar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-menu">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://www.greenmountainenergy.com/wp-content/themes/gmec-bones/library/images/gme-logo-spring2017-refresh.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <a href="" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
          </a>
            <div class="nav-menu-list">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="nav-menu-list-item item-1"><a href="">Plans And Services</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown dropdown-1">
                            <a href=""> <span>RESIDENTAL</span></a>
                            <li><a href="">Go Local Solar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar with Green Mountain Driver</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar All Nighter for EVs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Renewable Rewards® Buyback Plan</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Get a Quote on Home Solar Panels</a></li>
                            <li class="bold-text space"><a href="">View All Your Electricity Plans</a></li> 
                            <a href=""> <span>COMMERCIAL</span></a>
                            <li><a href="">Electricity for Small Business</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Commercial Solar Power</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar Buyback Program</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Channel Partners</a></li>
                            <li class="bold-text"><a href="">Get A Quote for Your Business</a></li>
                          </li>
                        </ul>  
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-menu-list-item item-2"><a href="">Why Do Green</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown dropdown-2">
                            <a href=""> <span>RESIDENTAL</span></a>
                            <li><a href="">Go Local Solar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar with Green Mountain Driver</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar All Nighter for EVs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Renewable Rewards® Buyback Plan</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Get a Quote on Home Solar Panels</a></li>
                            <li class="bold-text space"><a href="">View All Your Electricity Plans</a></li> 
                            <a href=""> <span>COMMERCIAL</span></a>
                            <li><a href="">Electricity for Small Business</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Commercial Solar Power</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar Buyback Program</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Channel Partners</a></li>
                            <li class="bold-text"><a href="">Get A Quote for Your Business</a></li>
                          </li>
                        </ul>  
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-menu-list-item item-3"><a href="">About Us</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown dropdown-3">
                            <a href=""> <span>RESIDENTAL</span></a>
                            <li><a href="">Go Local Solar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar with Green Mountain Driver</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar All Nighter for EVs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Renewable Rewards® Buyback Plan</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Get a Quote on Home Solar Panels</a></li>
                            <li class="bold-text space"><a href="">View All Your Electricity Plans</a></li> 
                            <a href=""> <span>COMMERCIAL</span></a>
                            <li><a href="">Electricity for Small Business</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Commercial Solar Power</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar Buyback Program</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Channel Partners</a></li>
                            <li class="bold-text"><a href="">Get A Quote for Your Business</a></li>
                          </li>
                        </ul>  
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-menu-list-item item-4"><a href="">Customer Service</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown dropdown-4">
                            <a href=""> <span>RESIDENTAL</span></a>
                            <li><a href="">Go Local Solar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar with Green Mountain Driver</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar All Nighter for EVs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Renewable Rewards® Buyback Plan</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Get a Quote on Home Solar Panels</a></li>
                            <li class="bold-text space"><a href="">View All Your Electricity Plans</a></li> 
                            <a href=""> <span>COMMERCIAL</span></a>
                            <li><a href="">Electricity for Small Business</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Commercial Solar Power</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Solar Buyback Program</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Channel Partners</a></li>
                            <li class="bold-text"><a href="">Get A Quote for Your Business</a></li>
                          </li>
                        </ul>  
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <div class="nav-menu-list2">
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="" class="item-1 orange-btn">View Plans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="item-2"> <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <span>My Account</span></a></li>
                 </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Based on the description of your question I guess I am confused as to what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Would you like the menu button to appear when the screen is small enough but disappear when it becomes larger again?

Comment: Yes, I want this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a menu like this?

[w3schools dropdown tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text)

It is also recommended to use `display: none` rather than `visibility: hidden` as the way css treats these two properities is very different.

It is not entirely clear whether you are trying to make multiple small menus or one big one with the bars, but the essence behind each one is

```
.myPositionClass {
    position: relative;
}
.myDropdownClass {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.myPositionClass:hover .myDropdownClass {
    display: block;
}

.
```

Where the html has an element with myDropdownClass inside an element with myPositionClass

Comment: I will try.Thanks.

Comment: I don't like hover, I want it to open when I click and click again to close. how can ı do?

Comment: :active or :target might do the trick for you. If you are looking for complex events to happen upon a click though you will need to use some js.